# CFRunLoopPerformBlock vs dispatch_async

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have some calculation work on background thread, after that I need to update the transform of some calayer, I try use

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{calayer.transform = newTransform});
```

and

```
CFRunLoopPerformBlock(CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes, ^(void) {calayer.transform = newTransform});
```

I just thought they are the same, 
but I found the calayer worked much smooth(maybe?) when using dispatch_async.
what is the different about these two functions?

Comment: Part of the smoothness you observed may have been the fact that in the guts of the run loop the blocks "sent" to the dispatch queue and the blocks "sent" to `CFRunLoopPerformBlock` are serviced at different logical "moments". This would depend a lot, of course, on what the blocks do in relation to the rest of the system and your app.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The primary difference here is that `CFRunLoopPerformBlock` allows you to specify specific run loop modes in which to execute the block, whereas `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),...)` is going to execute in common modes only. Perhaps more apropos to the performance issue you're seeing, `CFRunLoopPerformBlock` does *not* wake up the main thread. From the documentation for `CFRunLoopPerformBlock`:

> This method enqueues the block only and does not automatically wake up
>   the specified run loop. Therefore, execution of the block occurs the
>   next time the run loop wakes up to handle another input source. If you
>   want the work performed right away, you must explicitly wake up that
>   thread using the CFRunLoopWakeUp function.

In practice, this will usually mean that your block wont be executed until the time the run loop wakes up (i.e. user event occurs, timer fires, run loop source fires, mach message is received, etc.) GCD is not, by design, a run-loop based API; the relationship between the main queue and the main thread run loop is, effectively, an implementation detail. I would expect that implementation to wake up the run loop itself if that were necessary for the main queue to be serviced.

Absent information to the contrary, I strongly suspect this is the source of the difference in performance.  I would expect the performance to be similar if you added a call to `CFRunLoopWakeUp` immediately after your call to `CFRunLoopPerformBlock`.

Comment: You can avoid the need to call `CFRunLoopWakeUp` by using the slightly-higher-level methods provided by `NSRunLoop`, which call `CFRunLoopWakeUp` for you.

Answer (score 7):

GCD's main queue is a serial queue. So, it can only run a single task at a time. Even if that task runs an inner run loop — for example, runs a modal dialog — then other tasks submitted to the main queue can't run until that has completed.

Tasks submitted using `CFRunLoopPerformBlock()` can run whenever the run loop is run in one of the target modes. That includes if the run loop is run from within a task that was submitted using `CFRunLoopPerformBlock()`.

Consider the following examples:

```
CFRunLoopPerformBlock(CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes, ^{
    printf("outer task milestone 1\n");
    CFRunLoopPerformBlock(CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes, ^{
        printf("inner task\n");
    });
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
    printf("outer task milestone 2\n");
});
```

produces output like:

```
outer task milestone 1
inner task
outer task milestone 2
```

While this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    printf("outer task milestone 1\n");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        printf("inner task\n");
    });
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
    printf("outer task milestone 2\n");
});
```

produces:

```
outer task milestone 1
outer task milestone 2
inner task
```

Comment: One implication of this is that blocks "sent" to `CFRunLoopPerformBlock` must support re-entrance. If we assume we are sending a block to the main thread in order to be able to perform UI-related work, which is often at quite a high level of abstraction, this is important to consider.

Answer (score 3):

I sometimes use them together:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    CFRunLoopPerformBlock(CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, ^{
        // stuff
    });
});
```

I use this to send a block to the main thread that will execute without causing 'glitches' when a UIScrollview is scrolling.

I've also been recently using:

```
CFRunLoopPerformBlock(CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, ^{
    // stuff
});
```

in lieu of:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:myObject afterDelay:0]
```

in order to defer execution of code to the next pass through the runloop. This way I don't have to create a special method to contain the code I want to execute and don't have to wrap all of the parameters for execution into a single (id) myObject.

Comment: Just solved a problem after finding this solution 7 years later. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

One subtlety which can lead to serious trouble is due to a bug deep in CF blocks "sent" to `CFRunLoopPerformBlock` are not always invoked in the order they were sent. If order is important to your program, then you need to find a way to provide it yourself. For this reason as well as the nesting mentioned in another answer the documentation for `CFRunLoopPerformBlock` shouldn't use queue terminology. Sadly, this bug also propagates quietly up into some methods of `NSRunLoop` (because, of course, they call `CFRunLoopPerformBlock`).